# Error at "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

Tags: android, android-studio

I have encountered a problem at Android Studio when I just imported a project,
the sources is no problem I think,because it can be run at other computer.

But I just can't find a way to solve this error.

```
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:130)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.loadDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:75)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:128)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:294)
Error:Android Dex: [appPortal] ... 5 more
```

Comment: What is your buildToolsVersion ?

Comment: thank u ~I have solved this problem finally，it was a redundant SDK with a higher version was installed。